# Android Toolbar : Centre align a TextView in a toolbar having a menu

Tags: android, alignment, android-toolbar

I have a toolbar in my activity(not set as the actionbar). I have added a menu item to it.

```
toolBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(
            new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    // Handle the menu item

                    return true;
                }
            });

toolBar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
```

This has reduced the size of the toolbar leading to my textview no longer looking like it is centre horizontally.

**How do I centre align(at least make it look like) this textview in the toolbar while keeping the menu item/items that I have added?**

Answer (score 1):

Adding the attributes 
     **app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"** and **app:contentInsetStart="0dp"** attributes to the Toolbar widget in my layout
fixed this issue for me.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
 app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp">
```